# Extra arrow is showing after bootstrap dropdownmenu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

```
<div>
                                    <div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
                                          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            Admin<span class="caret"></span>
                                          </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[image]

This is the code..so how can i remove that extra arrow attached to button as shown in image?

CSS is as follows which is written in style.css:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 130px;
    /*padding-right: 34px;*/
    height: 34px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide fiddle or demo where we can the issue in action?

Comment: Share the CSS too in the post

Comment: please provide snippet or jsfiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after comment

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop Down
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Example2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Example3</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: after removing <span class="caret"></span>
it removes little arrow on button after "Admin"

Comment: no but the other arrow..read the question properly before giving answer. Thanx

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav Please check the code snippet. is it working now?

Comment: Please read how to answer on SO as user gave example with error screenshot and what you are offering as how to create bootstrap nav bar. Please don't post such type of low quality answer. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

after removing  `min-width: 130px;` from css it is looking fine